# Configuration of Related products magento 2

Tags: magento2

Does Magento2 not have Related products/ Cross sell products configuration in admin by default?

Should we have to install the 3rd party extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it does.
Go to the product add/edit admin page.
And you should see a section like this if you scroll down enough:

[image]

Click on any of the buttons and you will be able to add related products up-sells and cross-sells.

Comment: ok got it  now, thanks, but how to add for the already existing products?

Comment: Just edit the product and you will see the same tab in there.